# c# set property using different type than variable

Tags: c#, types, properties, blazor, shorthand

I am trying to set a variable whose value will be a percent (i.e. "20%") which would be a string, and will change based on the level of the element.
To calculate the level I have an integer.
I am trying to use the C# properties to get more used to them and practice, but am uncertain if what I am attempting is allowed.

```
public int Tier { get; set; } = 1;
    
private string _ContainerLeft {
        get { return _ContainerLeft; }
        set
        {
            int left = (( value - 1) * 2) + 10;
            _ContainerLeft = left.ToString() + "%";
        }
    }

protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        _ContainerLeft = Tier;
    }
```

This is the code for the variable. I take the value passed in (an integer), do some math to calculate the base case and growth, then convert it to the final string.

However, I get errors that "value - 1" can't be performed on a string and int, and on the "Tier" at the bottom that it isn't of type string.

I realize there are plenty of ways around these (although I don't know the best) such as doing some .toString(), int.Parse(), and casting. But I am more concerned with if this is possible without type manipulation.

Comment: "But I am more concerned with if this is possible without type manipulation." How do you propose to subtract 1 from a string without any type manipulation?

Comment: @JonSkeet Maybe this is where my confusion comes from, but in my mind I'm not subtracting one from a string.
I pass the set function the variable Tier(int). This populates the variable "value" as an int. I then calculate a result using "value"(int). Then modify it and convert it to a string to set the variable "_ContainerLeft" to the result which is a string.

Comment: In your setter, you're using `value - 1`. The type of the `value` variable is `string`, because it's in the context of the setter for a `string` property. It would be initialized by something like `_ContainerLeft = "SomeValue";` - so how is the expression `value - 1` *not* trying to subtract 1 from a string? You can't set `_ContainerLeft = Tier;` either, for the same reason - you're trying to assign an `int` value to a `string` property.

Comment: Note that your `_ContainerLeft` getter would also overflow, because it just calls itself. Basically I think you should review the whole code, as I don't think it's doing what you expect it to be doing...

Comment: I suppose my hope was that the set property for a variable operated like a generic function. So I could pass in any value, so long as the result was setting the variable to its type; in this case, a string. But if its the case that you have to pass the set property a same typed value, even if that value isn't directly tied to the end result, then I understand why my attempt here wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, a property is effectively `PropertyType get_Property()` and `void set_Property(PropertyType value)`. There's no such thing really as a "set property for a variable" - there's just "a property". The property implementation may or may not use a variable, but that's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally when you write `_ContainerLeft = Tier` and `int left = ((value -1) * 2)` you are trying to do maths with a mixture of integers and strings, which will not work in C#.

Languages like javascript will try to give you some sort of answer (even if it's not what you might expect) but you *have* to convert from one to another in some way.

Typically I would suggest you make container left a method, and call it using the integer value of Tier

```
public string ContainerLeft()
{
    var left = ((Tier - 1) * 2) + 10;
    return $"{left}%"; // string interpolation is nice
}
```

This will compile fine, and will react to changes in `Tier` apart from the initial `OnInitialized()`